# Помогите составить регулярное выражение Java regex

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Помогите плиз составить регулярное выражение

```
<option disabled="" value="">---</option><option value="2089974">Shimano/SRAM HG 10/11-speed</option><option value="2089975">SRAM XDR 11/12s</option>
```

мне нужно собрать значения опций и разделить их символом (разделитель например | или другим)

Shimano/SRAM HG 10/11-speed|SRAM XDR 11/12s
привести к такому виду

Answer (score 0):

Можно написать **регулярное выражение** вот так:
[`<option(?!\sdisabled).*?>(.*?)</option>`](https://regex101.com/r/Pkxp97/1)

Здесь ищем группы `(.*?)` между тегами **<option></option>**, при этом в самом теге могут быть какие угодно атрибуты `.*?`, но не должно быть **disabled** `(?!\sdisabled)`.

#### [Код](https://jdoodle.com/a/6fyJ) на [java](/questions/tagged/java):

```java
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
      String s = "<option disabled=\"\" value=\"\">---</option><option value=\"2089974\">Shimano/SRAM HG 10/11-speed</option><option value=\"2089975\">SRAM XDR 11/12s</option>";
      String regex = "<option(?!\sdisabled).*?>(.*?)</option>";
      String result = "";
      
      Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
      Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
      
      while (m.find()) {
          result += m.group(1) + "|";
      }
      result = result.replaceAll(".$", "");
      System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

###### Вывод:

```
Shimano/SRAM HG 10/11-speed|SRAM XDR 11/12s
```

В `while (m.find())` забираем все группы и добавляем в `result`, в качестве разделителя также добавляем "**|**".
Как группы заканчиваются, убираем разделитель в конце результирующей строковой переменной.

Answer (score 0):

Вариант регулярки, в которой проверяется наличие непустого атрибута `value` в теге `option` и непустое содержимое самого тега: `<option value=\"\\d+\">([^<]+)</option>`.

Также можно использовать Stream API (Java 9+) для получения потока нужных совпадений и конкатенации в одну строку с разделителем `"|"`:

```java
public static String getOptions(String str) {
    return Pattern.compile("<option value=\"\\d+\">([^<]+)</option>", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE)
        .matcher(str)
        .results() // Stream<MatchResult>
        .map(mr -> mr.group(1)) // группа 1 содержит текст внутри тега
        .collect(Collectors.joining("|"));
}
```

Тест:

```java
System.out.println(getOptions(
"<option disabled=\"\" value=\"\">---</option><OPTION value=\"2089974\">Shimano/SRAM HG 10/11-speed</option><option value=\"2089975\">SRAM XDR 11/12s</option>"
));
```

```
Shimano/SRAM HG 10/11-speed|SRAM XDR 11/12s
```